# How to get field joined by third table in JPA

Tags: jpa

I have 3 tables:

**object** with **object_id** and **field_name**

**object_form** with **object_id** and **form_id**

and **object_fields** with **form_id** and **field_desc**

So I can get all the objects with field_names, but I need to get field_desc. In SQL it would be something like:

```
select o.object_id, f.field_desc 
from object o, object_form of, object_fields f
where o.object_id = of.object_id
and of.form_id = f.form_id
```

How can I do it in JPA?

Comment: Since this question is about JPA, it would really help to describe your object model. You need to stop thinking tables and start thinking object. Please provide your object model (and the mapping).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using a unidirectional one-to-many relationship mapping.

Hope this helps. 
RG

```
@Entity
@Table(name="OBJECT")
public class MyObject
{
    @Id
    @Column(name="OBJECT_ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="FIELD_NAME")
    private String fieldName;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name="OBJECT_FORM",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="OBJECT_ID"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="FORM_ID"))
    private Collection<MyObjectField> objectFields;

    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="OBJECT_FIELDS")
public class MyObjectField
{
    @Id
    @Column(name="FORM_ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="FIELD_DESC")
    private String fieldDescription;

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly counter-intuitive, but this is probably best mapped using `@ManyToMany`  mapping.

Consider that your table structure accommodates the situation where a given `form_id` is associated with more than one `object_id`, and vice versa. Even if your business logic forbids this, this is the model of the relationship.

Check out [this article](http://sieze.wordpress.com/2009/09/04/mapping-a-many-to-many-join-table-with-extra-column-using-jpa/) and [this code sample](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JPA/ManyToManyJoinedTable.htm) on how to do this. It's difficult to give a specific example since you've told us nothing about your class model.